# Execute the script while cloning Virtualbox VM

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dns, virtualbox, startup

I'm trying to create a virtualbox VM using following commands.

- `VBoxManage createvm --name "vm_name" --ostype Ubuntu_64 --register`
- `VBoxManage storageattach "vm_name" --storagectl "sata1" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium base_ubuntu.vdi --mtype multiattach`
- `VBoxManage startvm "vm_name"`

I'm able to create VM's and it's up and running now I need to execute the script for the first-time while creating vm for updating dns server(dns-nameserver) not after every reboot.

Is it possible, hacks are all cool for this?

Comment: Have you saved the commands to a file? Then simply type `bash filename`. In order to run the file directly (i.e. via `./filename`) you have to first run `chmod +x filename`, and you have to include a shebang line in the file.

Comment: Sorry, my question was sort of ambiguous. What I'm trying to do is: while cloning it should execute some bash script. 
Similar to user-data in aws-ec2.